# A strange way of writing query encountered

Tags: sql

This may seems the most dumbest question ever on stackoverflow but I am just wondering why would you write such a query:

```
Select e1.Emploee_ID, e1.Departement_ID From Employee e 
Inner join Employee E1 on e.employee_id= e1.Employee_ID
Inner join Departement d on d.dep_id= e1.departement_id
```

Why do we have to join on employee? my obvious query would be

```
select e.employee_ID, e.Departement_id from employee e 
inner join  Departement d on d.dep_id= e1.departement_id
```

Comment: After a few glances, all I see is a possible typo\brain fart on the original author's behalf :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Referencing the PK with an inner join **is redundant**.

You would normally join on the same table to link with another record, for example if you have a FK-column that reference the boss of an employee.

Assuming you would have a nullable foreign-key column `Boss_ID` in table `Employee`

```
Select e.Employee_ID, boss.Employee_id, d.Departement_ID 
From Employee e  
LEFT OUTER JOIN Employee boss on boss.Employee_ID=e.Boss_ID
INNER JOIN Departement d on d.dep_id= e.departement_id
```

Note that i've used a LEFT OUTER JOIN to get also the employee that have no bosses.

Comment: Tim,Thanks that sound like the most accurate explanation

Answer (score 0):

What I can see. You do not need this join.

```
Inner join Employee E1 on e.employee_id= e1.Employee_ID
```

The two queries will give the same result. I can not see the point of `JOIN`ing twice on the `Employee` table.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see any reason to join Employee to Employee in this query. In the past I've occasionally used two subsets of the same table in the same query, but there's nothing like that going on here. To me it looks like this was done by mistake.

Comment: thanks that was my opinion as well but I am seeing these types of joint in the application I am maintaining and obviously don't know why it was written like that and it is so common in this application

Answer (score 0):

If  **employee_id** is a PK then it doesn't make sense, but if it is not the two queries will return different results.

The first query will not return NULL employee_id and will return **N^2** results for multiple entries with N occurrences.

Answer (score 0):

Even simpler would be this:

> select e.employee_ID, d.dep_name from employee e,Departement d   where  d.dep_id= e.departement_id

Comment: sorry i think i misunderstood the question